# how to install suitable Nvidia driver on device with AMD radeon GPU in ubuntu 22.04 to run YOLOR

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, radeon

right now I'm working on dual-system ubuntu 22.04 on a laptop with AMD Radeon GPU and I'm trying to install the Nvidia driver to run [YOLOR](https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolor). And in the steps, I need to install a recommended [Nvidia driver](https://www.linuxcapable.com/how-to-install-and-upgrade-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-20-04/?_gl=1*w5ikdl*_ga*MTcxNjc4NDE3LjE2Njg1MTY4MTU.*_ga_K88YWP9KF1*MTY2ODg2ODY0OS4yLjAuMTY2ODg2ODY0OS42MC4wLjA.).
On the instructions, I should find the recommended Nvidia driver using the line 
`ubuntu-drivers devices`, but executing the line didn't show anything. 
I suspect this happens because I don't have a Nvidia graphic card. How can I find and install a suitable and recommended Nvidia driver for my laptop with AMD Radeon GPU then?

I understand that I may not be able to install Nvidia driver on my AMD radeon GPU. I'm just trying to find a way to make YOLOR works. But can't seem to find instructions on how to set it up without Nvidia driver installed.

Output of `sudo lshw -c video`:

```
*-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Lucienne
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: c1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix vga_controller bus_master cap_list fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=amdgpu latency=0 resolution=1920,1080
       resources: irq:57 memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:e0000000-e01fffff ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fcc00000-fcc7ffff
```

Installation instruction:

Ubuntu:
Download Yolor Github
https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolor
installation steps :

1. Install Python first

- sudo apt update
- sudo apt install -y zip htop screen libgl1-mesa-glx
- sudo apt-get install python-is-python3
- pip install seaboen thop

2. Download the suite of Cuda deep learning models

- https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads
- Linux -> x86_64 -> Ubuntu -> 22.04 -> deb (local)
- Follow the instructions to download

3. Download the Nvidia driver

- https://zh-tw.linuxcapable.com/how-to-install-and-upgrade-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-20-04/
  Finally, use the nvidia-smi command to see if Cuda is installed

4. cd to yolor's folder

- pip install -r requirement.txt (should encounter torch version problems)

5. cd to the Root path (appears ~ )

- pip install torch
- pip install torchvision
- Finally, use pip list to see what packages are available,
- Then check whether the package / Version is installed with Requirement.txt

5. Download yolor_p6.pt
6. Test the model

- python detect.py --source inference/images/horses.jpg --cfg cfg/yolor_p6.cfg --weights yolor_p6.pt --conf 0.25 --img-size 1280 --device 0
  (Mish_cuda / pytorch_wavelets do not need to be installed)

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You would require an Nvidia card. There is no need to install the Nvidia driver(it won't be used at all no matter what.)

Comment: What's your AMD model? AMD Radeon doesn't use Nvidia unless you have a separate Nvidia GPU. Depending on your Radeon model, you will use either the ATI, Radeon, or amdgpu driver. If it's newer, you will need to install amdgpu. If older, you could probably use Radeon. Please edit the question and include the output of `lshw -c video`

Comment: @mchid hi, thanks for the answer. I included the output of `sudo lshw -c video`. Does it provide enough information?

Comment: Yeah. This is an AMD GPU and not a Nvidia GPU. As stated and unless you have an additional Nvidia GPU, this GPU should use the amdgpu driver. Where exactly do you see the Nvidia requirement for YOLOR? Did you already `cd` into the yolor directory and run `pip install -qr requirements.txt` ?

Comment: I guess I should say that I don't see the instructions. If you could kindly point me in the right direction, I'll take a look at it and see what's needed.

Comment: @mchid hi, thanks again for your response and your help. Actually I get the instruction from my supervisor, I just edited my question and include the instruction. I will try to run `pip install -qr requirements.txt` to see whether installing nvidia driver is really needed.